# Ask user to open exe after download (for example remote control help)

Tags: javascript, browser

**Is this possible: "Ask user to open exe after download?"**

Actual:

- To solve a problem for customers (especially older ones and people with disabilities), i mail a Remote Control exe per link.
- This link also has separate "pictured HowTos" for each browser (detects: ie/Chrome/Firefox) for downloading & running exe.
- Especially Firefox is very complex for the target group. (hidden menu, min 3 clicks)

Of course, opening an exe from browser is not a big problem for us IT Admins and we cannot even imagine, that it would be one. But some people really have a problem.

**So, is there any Javascript or something else to ask the user to open the exe?**

- *Page has EV-SSL and exe is EV-signed*
- *I don't ask for auto-open exe. I know this would be a security risk. I only would like to help the user starting the exe easier.*

Comment: As far as I know there is no means to do what you're looking for. What you _could_ do is try to detect the browser, then show a browser-specific guide after the download has been started.

Comment: This is what i actual do: separate "pictured HowTos" for each browser. But i hope there is a better way.

Comment: I think much of the complication is probably because it is still a security, even if the exe doesn't auto-open and pretty much for the same reasons why you want to do this: users don't understand what they do with a computer, so if a malicious attacker can "trick" them into executing a binary then that's almost as good as auto-executing it.

Comment: Of course. "users don't understand what they do with a computer" - so they ask for help from an IT-Admin ;)

Comment: An IT-Admin or a scammer posing as one. The very same problem makes them unable to know the difference.